# Find the coordinate of the point at which each straight line crosses the co-ordinate axes?

Tags: coordinate-systems

Find the coordinate of the point at which each straight line crosses the co-ordinate axes?

5x-3y = 10

is (0,10/3) the answer?

Answer (score 0):

$5x-3y=10\Rightarrow y=\dfrac{5x-10}{3}$. If $y=0$ then $5x=10\Rightarrow x=2$. So a point where that line intersects the $x$-axis is $(2,0)$. If $x=0$ then $y=-\dfrac{10}{3}$. So a second point where that line intersects the $y$-axis is $(0,-\dfrac{10}{3})$.